# How to run GSConnect Gnome Extension

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, kde-connect

I've installed Gnome Shell Extension using Ubuntu 20.04. I was then able to install the Clipboard Indicator extension which then showed up on the top right of the screen (Systray?). I installed the GSConnect extension but it did not have an icon showing in the Systray. I've no idea how to run it. GSConnect is not showing as a process in Systems Monitor. I've put an appropriate comment issue on the extension's web page, but there's no reply. BTW KDE Connect app on my Android phone doesn't see any device: it should see the Ubuntu box if GSConnect was running Ok. Any ideas on how to make GSConnect run?

Answer (score 0):

To see the icon of GSConnect in the tray, you may need to install the extension [AppIndicator/KStatusNotifier](https://github.com/ubuntu/gnome-shell-extension-appindicator)

Comment: AppIndicator/KStatusNotifier installed Ok. I still don't see GSConnect in the tray. Both it & the App.... extension.. one are switched on according to Gnome Shell Extensions app. When I click on the Settings icon for GSConnect it is running because it says 'Searching for devices' (with KDE Connect running on my phone which doesn't see my Ubuntu box). However, GSConnect doesn't have a process running of that or similar name according to System Monitor.

Comment: Did you notice that both devices (your phone and your computer) must be connected to the same Wifi network to see each other?

Comment: They are connected to the same network.